# Can't add ADO.NET Data Service item in VS 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net

When I go to add item, there isn't ADO.NET Data Service item to choose.
I work in .Net 4.0, VS 2010. My project is a Wcf service.
I'm following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

and here is how they add it:
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC242592.jpg

Comment: @marc_s Tnx. Can you answer this question, so that I can choose your answer as best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **ADO.NET Data Service** was renamed **WCF Data Service** in November 2009

And since this is a REST-based service that lives and breathes HTTP, you can only add this within a **Web Application** or **Web Site** project - you cannot add it to other project types.